# Usage of a BlockwiseBijector in MCMC?

Tags: tensorflow, mcmc, tensorflow-probability, bijection

I want to run MCMC with 203 parameters and want to apply different bijectors to the first, second, third and the rest of the parameters separately. How do I do this without running into errors? I am currently using a `Blockwise`-Bijector with `block_sizes=[1, 1, 1, 200]` and want to use it as given in the following minimal example, but cannot run without errors:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions
tfb = tfp.bijectors

# dummy log probability
def log_prob_fn(state):
  return tfd.Normal(state, 1.).log_prob(tf.ones_like(state))

# create kernel
kernel = tfp.mcmc.NoUTurnSampler(
    target_log_prob_fn=log_prob_fn,
    step_size=1.0,
)

# this is the bijector that does not work in MCMC
bijector = tfb.Blockwise([
    tfb.Softplus(),  
    tfb.Sigmoid(), 
    tfb.Softplus(),  
    tfb.Softplus()],  
    block_sizes=[1, 1, 1, 200],
    maybe_changes_size=False)

# dummy state
init_state = tfd.Normal(tf.ones(203), 1.).sample()

transformed_kernel = tfp.mcmc.TransformedTransitionKernel(
    inner_kernel=kernel,
    bijector=bijector
)

adaptive_kernel = tfp.mcmc.DualAveragingStepSizeAdaptation(
    transformed_kernel,
    num_adaptation_steps=1600,
    target_accept_prob=.60)

# Run the MCMC chains
samples = tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
    num_results=10000,
    num_burnin_steps=2000,
    current_state=init_state,
    kernel=adaptive_kernel,
    trace_fn=None
)
```

I cannot use it in `tfp.mcmc.sample_chain()` without getting the following warnings and error.

```
WARNING: Nested component "jointmap" in composition "blockwise_of_softplus_and_sigmoid_and_softplus_and_softplus" operates on inputs with increased degrees of freedom. This may result in an incorrect log_det_jacobian.
WARNING: Nested component "concat" in composition "blockwise_of_softplus_and_sigmoid_and_softplus_and_softplus" operates on inputs with increased degrees of freedom. This may result in an incorrect log_det_jacobian.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\sample.py", line 330, in sample_chain
    previous_kernel_results = kernel.bootstrap_results(current_state)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\dual_averaging_step_size_adaptation.py", line 538, in bootstrap_results
    inner_results = self.inner_kernel.bootstrap_results(init_state)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\transformed_kernel.py", line 492, in bootstrap_results
    inner_results=self._inner_kernel.bootstrap_results(
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\nuts.py", line 468, in bootstrap_results
    ] = leapfrog_impl.process_args(self.target_log_prob_fn, dummy_momentum,
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\internal\leapfrog_integrator.py", line 378, in process_args
    [target, target_grad_parts] = mcmc_util.maybe_call_fn_and_grads(
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\internal\util.py", line 297, in maybe_call_fn_and_grads
    result, grads = _value_and_gradients(fn, fn_arg_list, result, grads)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\internal\util.py", line 268, in _value_and_gradients
    result = fn(*fn_arg_list)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\transformed_kernel.py", line 126, in transformed_log_prob_fn
    return tlp + ldj_fn(state_parts, event_ndims)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\transformed_kernel.py", line 58, in fn
    return sum([
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\mcmc\transformed_kernel.py", line 59, in <listcomp>
    getattr(b, attr)(sp, event_ndims=e)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\bijector.py", line 1640, in forward_log_det_jacobian
    return self._call_forward_log_det_jacobian(x, event_ndims, name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\composition.py", line 501, in _call_forward_log_det_jacobian
    return self._forward_log_det_jacobian(x, event_ndims, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\composition.py", line 513, in _forward_log_det_jacobian
    bm.bijector.forward_log_det_jacobian(bm.x, bm.x_event_ndims,
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\bijector.py", line 1640, in forward_log_det_jacobian
    return self._call_forward_log_det_jacobian(x, event_ndims, name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\bijector.py", line 1557, in _call_forward_log_det_jacobian
    reduce_shape, assertions = ldj_reduction_shape(
  File "C:\Users\tobia\miniconda3\envs\idm\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_probability\python\bijectors\bijector.py", line 2219, in ldj_reduction_shape
    raise ValueError('`event_ndims must be at least {}. Saw: {}.'
ValueError: `event_ndims must be at least 1. Saw: 0.
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I checked that I can do forward and inverse passes with this bijector by passing the init_state for testing. This works as expected. Only in MCMC it fails. I also tried other bijectors like `JointMap` or `Composition` but it didn't work.

Comment: Resolved it myself. The error was not in the bijector but in the shape of the log probability not matching my chains.